# How to use print() along with other operations in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a directory of CSV data files and I load all of them in one line using `pandas.read_csv()` within a list comprehension statement.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
file_list = glob.glob('../data/')
df_list = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list]
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Now I want to print the file path every time when it loads a data file, but I cannot find a way to use multiple statements in list comprehension. For example, something like `[pd.read_csv(f); print(f) for f in file_list]` will cause a `SyntaxError`.

The closest thing I can get is to let `print()` to return `None` in an if-statement, which works like a `pass` after printing.

```
df_list = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list if print(f) is None]
```

Is there a proper way of doing this? I like list comprehension for its conciseness, but it does not seem to allow multiple statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a list comprehension (understandable given the speed improvement over a `for` loop), you could slightly modify your solution because `None` is falsy:

```
df_list = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list if not print(f)]
```

Alternatively make a function that does the work:

```
def read_and_print(f):
    print(f)
    return pd.read_csv(f)

df_list = [read_and_print(f) for f in file_list]
```

However, the approaches violate the Command–query separation principle that Python generally follows because the function has both a side-effect and a `return` value of interest. Nonetheless, I think these are quite pragmatic, particularly if you want to `print()` now to view the data, but later you plan to remove the `print()` calls.

Comment: anyone know a resource explaining bool(print("hey")) ? It'll always evaluate Falsy (I think) because it's not returning anything

Comment: @BrendanMetcalfe `print()` returns `None`, which is falsy. try `p = print(1); print(p)`

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension was not designed for that. Rather, just for populating a list looping over some iterable, and (optionally) if a condition is met. Python likes to emphasise readability over lines of code.

The proper way to do what you want is to not use list comprehension at all, rather a for loop:

```
for f in file_list:
    print(f)
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(f))
```

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, you should generally not use functions with side-effects in a list comprehension. However, I appreciate that *for debugging purposes* something like this might be useful.

One way, similar to your `if` condition, would be to use `or`, making use of the fact that the `print` function returns `None` and thus evaluating and returning the second operator:

```
df_list = [print(f) or pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list]
```

But this might be difficult to understand and the intention not very clear. Alternatively, you could define a `peek` function that prints and returns the argument and use that in the comprehension:

```
def peek(x, *args, **kwargs):
    print(x, *args, **kwargs)
    return x

df_list = [pd.read_csv(peek(f)) for f in file_list]
```

You could also make this more generic, passing the function to be applied (`print` in this case) as another parameter to the `peek` function, or first checking whether some global `debug_enabled` variable is actually set to `True`.